# Change dtype of a ndarray such that the shape also changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to combine two bytes of my ndarray such that horizontally the shape is reduced by half.
E.g. I would like to go from following array -

```
>>> np.full((4,4),0xff,dtype='u1')
array([[255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

to -

```
>>> np.full((4,2),0xffff,dtype='u2')
array([[65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535]], dtype=uint16)
```

How can I do this?  I am working in Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view-casting:

```
>>> a = np.arange(16,dtype="u1").reshape(4,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a.view("<u2") # little endian
array([[ 256,  770],
       [1284, 1798],
       [2312, 2826],
       [3340, 3854]], dtype=uint16)
>>> a.view(">u2") # big endian
array([[   1,  515],
       [1029, 1543],
       [2057, 2571],
       [3085, 3599]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: This is amazing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit operations. I would define the data type for the original array as `'u2'`, or something that will handle a 16-bit number.

```
arr = np.full((4, 4), 0xff, dtype='u2')
arr[::2] << 8 | arr[1::2]
```

Result:

```
array([[65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535],
       [65535, 65535]], dtype=uint16)
```